# Correct path env for Java SDK and runtime

Tags: java

I am reasonably new to Java and want to know how to set the path on Windows XP.  When I install the Java v1.7 JDK it seems to install to a JDK and a jre directory.  I assume first for compiler/dev stuff eg javac and the latter for the jvm / runtime stuff.  If I set the path to the jdk\bin directory then everything seems to work but is that correct?  Do I need to set a path to the jre\bin?

I initially will not be using any IDE such as Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to set a path to the jre/bin directory. The JDK directory actually contains everything you need. The JRE directory is basically what you get if you install *just* the JRE (for non-development purposes, just to run the code). It's not entirely clear to me why the two are installed separately, to be honest, but you definitely don't need the jre/bin directory on your path.

Comment: So <rest_of_path>\jdkvwhateverversion\bin is fine?

Comment: @user619818: That's certainly what I do :)